# How to check where entity framework is saving data to?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have just created a new c# application with entity framework. When I do the test start of my app, strangely enough, the entity framework is saving/reading data somewhere O.o

My local sql database server doesn't have any new databases/records, my app.config doesn't contain any connection strings.

Is there some wizardy going on here, or am I missing something? How do I find the connection string currently used by EF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string connStr = Context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
```

If you want the database name specifically, you can use:

```
string dbName = Context.Database.Connection.Database;
```